# Ordering query using lambda expression and Include method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working on a Entity-Framework-Core 2.0 query. The query needs to sort 2 tables by the "order" field. So far that's what I have:

```
return await _context.FieldsetGroup
                .Include(e => e.Fieldsets.OrderBy(o => o.Order))
                .ThenInclude(e => e.FieldsetFields.OrderBy(o => o.Field.Order))
                .ThenInclude(e => e.Field)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(fsg => fsg.FieldsetGroupId == fieldSetGroupId);
```

This query returns an exception:
"The property expression 'e => {from Fieldset o in e.Fieldsets orderby [o].Order asc select [o]}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393."

How can I sort the 2 tables?

Comment: You can't order inside an `Include`

Comment: so, where should I put it?

Comment: either use the .Join method which allows you to join modified DbSet/IQueryables or sort the navigation property after retrieval of your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the slower parts of database queries is the transport of your selected data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of transferred data.

Apparently your `FieldSetGroup` has zero or more `FieldSets`. Each `FieldSet` belongs to exactly one `FieldsetGroup`. This is identified by the foreign key `FieldSetGroupId`. The value of this field equals the `Id` of the `FieldSetGroup`.

So if you have `FieldSetGroup`with Id = 10, and this `FieldSetGroup` has, 1000 `FieldSets`, then every `FieldSet` will have a value of foreign key `FieldSetGroupId` of 10. No need to transfer this value 1000 times.

> Advice: To limit the amount of transferred data, avoid transferring more data than needed, use `Select` instead of `Include` and select only the data you actually plan to
>   use. Use `Include` if you plan to update the fetched data.

If you use `Select`, you can order whatever you want:

```
var result = dbContext.FieldsetGroup
   .Where((fieldSetGroup => fieldSetGroup.FieldsetGroupId == fieldSetGroupId)
   .Select(fieldSetGroup => new
   {
       ... // select the fieldSetGroup properties you plan to use

       FieldSets = fieldSetGroup.FieldSets
           .OrderBy(fieldSet => fieldSet.Order)
           .Select(fieldSet => new
           {
                ... // only select the fieldSet properties you plan to use

                FieldSetFields = fieldSet.FieldSetFields
                    .OrderBy(fieldSetField => fieldSetField.Order)
                    .Select(fieldSetField => new
                    {
                        ...
                    })
                    .ToList(),
                })
                .ToList(),
           })
           .ToList(),
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do sorting (`OrderBy`) inside the `Include` method. Sort the data after the query.